# parallelization alternative to parallel calls to a function?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pathos

Dear python parallel gurus,

I have devised a parallelization scheme that relies on a `serial_worker` function:

```
import pathos
import multiprocessing
pool = pathos.pools.ProcessPool(ncpus=n_cores)
amps=[None,] * len(tr)  # tr is a long array
for i, _amps in enumerate(pool.map(serial_worker, tr)):
    amps[i] = _amps
pool.terminate()
```

I understand there's a big overhead in python when summoning a function. Here I call `serial_worker` for `len(tr)` times. Can I do away with the function? Below is the complete problem showcasing how I ended up with a `serial_worker` function:

```
import numpy as np
import pathos  # enables pickling serial_worker
import multiprocessing

# bi and q are modest size arrays
bi = np.random.rand(42)
q = np.random.rand(10, 3)
tr = np.random.rand(10000, 42, 3)  # first dimension is very looong

def serial_worker(frame):
    """frame.shape = (42, 3)
    Uses arrays q and bi defined previously, a sort of closure 
    """
    exponents = np.tensordot(frame, q, axes=(1, 1))  # shape=(42, 10)
    exponentials = np.exp(1j * exponents)
    return np.tensordot(bi, exponentials, axes=1)  # shape=(10,)

pool = pathos.pools.ProcessPool(ncpus=n_cores)
amps=[None,] * len(tr)  # tr is a long array
for i, _amps in enumerate(pool.map(serial_worker, tr)):
    amps[i] = _amps
pool.terminate()
```

I am hiding `q` and `bi` within `serial_worker` at the expense of calling a function every time. Can anyone suggest other parallelization schemes?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to optimize at this level, just use a different language. The added overhead of 10000 function calls is less about 0.7 ms on my machine. This is going to be completely swamped by the overhead of multiprocessing to begin with.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga by "the overhead of multiprocessing", do you mean the time it takes to instantiate  the python interpreter and its related environment? Are there other factors contributing to "the overhead of multiprocessing"?